# Hide partial views from users, but make them available to AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So basically I have a single page application with Angular that is working together with ASP.NET MVC. I have a controller that has only partial views and I want the user to not be able to access them.

Normally for this I would use `[ChildActionOnly]`, but I am not calling my MVC partials from the view, but from AJAX (I do this with both jQuery and angular in different parts of the app).

Is there a way to block the user from accessing my partials, yet letting ajax get them when they click links?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it sounds out of the box to handle this using an `AuthorizationAttribute`, you conceivably do it.

```
public class AjaxOnlyAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            //..No Go
        }
    }
}
```

And then....

```
[AjaxOnlyAuthorization]
public MyAjaxOnlyClass
{
}
```

It is probally more appropriate to use an `ActionFilterAttribute` instead because the response format has little to do with authorization.

```
public class AjaxOnlyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the way I use authentication I believe this might be my preferred approach for now. If my application was using Identity in it's fullness roles would be preferred though. Thanks!

Comment: See my comment. The ActionFilterAttribute may be more appropriate.

Comment: After trying it a few times it seems it never hits the base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext); call, regardless of using the URL or the angular bound nav that calls that action. Is there a clue of what IsAjaxRequest does underneath?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment. IsAjaxRequest seems to ask for 'X-Requested-With' == 'XMLHttpRequest' to be true. Adding $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; to Angular config did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the data annotation Authorize? You can of course change the "Admin" to any group or user, or just use it without any users or roles to it:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

You add this just above the class or above each action that you want to restrict

You can of course do only [Authorize] above your class declaration to make sure one has to be logged in, and then do it more specifically on each action by declaring who is authorized to use the actions

Comment: The thing with my app though is that I don't use all of what Identity offers. I implemented my own authentication to work with the Authorize attribute, which means that I don't have roles configured. I can configure a "Developer" role and use it that way though.